# Selection in expected linear time: Why am I getting $O(n)$ bound instead of $\Omega(n \lg n)$?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, search-algorithms

The problem is from CLRS 9.3-1:

> In the algorithm `SELECT`, the input elements are divided into groups of
>   $5$. Argue that `SELECT` does not run in linear time if groups of $3$ are used.

If we do the "divide by $3$" technique, we will come up with this recurrence --

$$T(n) = \begin{cases}
\Theta(1) & \text{if $n \le K$} \\
T(\lceil n/3 \rceil)+T(2n/3+4) + O(n) & \text{if $n \ge K$} 
\end{cases}$$

I have solved by substituting $T(n) \le cn$ and  $O(n) = an$ --

$$\begin{aligned}
T(n) & \le \lceil n/3 \rceil + c(2n/3 + 4) + an \\
     & \le cn/3 + c + 2cn/3 + 4c + an \\
     & = cn + 5c + an \\
     & = (c+a)n + 5c \\
     & = c_1n + c_2 \le c_1n \approx O(n)
\end{aligned}$$

But the solution says it should be $\Omega(n \lg n)$. I understand that substitution like $cn \lg n$ could give $\Omega(n \lg n)$ bound, but what is wrong with $O(n)$ formulation above?

Comment: See [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) for proper techniques to use here. Also, this issue is *specifically* addressed in CLRS.

Comment: @Raphael That's my bad, I did not pay heed to that chapter well. Thanks for the links and the suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You started with the induction hypothesis $T(k) \le ck/3$ for all $k<n$, but you didn't prove that $T(n)\le cn$.  You concluded that $T(n) \le c_1 n$, for a **different** constant $c_1 \ne c$.  For the induction proof to work, you have to use the **same** constant in the induction hypothesis and the conclusion.